Remote repository on VScode
I am starting to work on a repository which is on github from vscode. My files in the project cannot import each other.in vs code terminal which is local I cannot find repository and also since I have push and commit access and source control tracks my changes so I dont need clone that. How can import files to each other.
I tried usual import codes but they don’t work. Also I tried to direct to repo from terminal but I font have it because it is remote.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you trying to import a Python library that is located on GitHub without having cloned it to your local computer?

Yes. But when I add it as remote repository it is technically cloned. Am not sure about that I need to clone it or not.

I have 2 .py files and one uses another function but when theI import that it doesnt know that module.

Open your terminal and run:
git clone https://github.com/your-username/your-repo.git
cd your-repo
code .

